# Unable to clone UserControl with XamlWriter in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I need to clone an UserControl (TabItem Content) for including it into a Canvas. I've tried with XamlWriter bur it throws NullReference Exception..

```
string gridXaml = XamlWriter.Save(Plot.Plot_MV.plotWindow.bremsPlot.Content);
```

here my .xaml

```
<TabControl x:Name="plot_TabControl" Margin="0" 
                    Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=TabControl_Style}" SelectionChanged="plot_TabControl_SelectionChanged" 
                    >

            <TabItem Header="Bremskraft" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=TabItem_Style}"
                x:Name="bremsPlot" Margin="0,0,0,40">
            </TabItem>
```

in code behind I include the content by creating a new UserControl class

```
bremsPlot.Content = new Bremskraft.Bremskraft_Plot(calcClass);
```

Comment: There is not enough information.
How do you convert it? As object or as concrete type?
What is calcClass?

Comment: The Content of the TabItem is a UserControl with Grid and Canvas and a Plot from Oxyplot. Just need the UserControl as UIelement for putting it into the Canvas. 
calcClass is a class with variables I need to bind with my UserControl

Comment: What are you trying to clone? What is the type of object you want to clone?
Where is the code that throws an exception?
Where is the exception happens?

Comment: I'm Trying to clone the Content of the TabItem, the whole UserControl. The code that thrwos the exception is in another class. 
The Exception is throwing from XamlWriter.Save(uielement). But when I ask if uielement = null it's false...

Comment: Don't clone everything. Clone only Model, even not ViewModel.
As far as I understand you're trying to put invalid type as parameter.
Check carefully expected types for your third parties component methods expect to receive, and verify that they are correct.
Add more details here or ask your third parties customer service.